# jQuery ajax request not triggering JS response from rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a standard controller which is set up to respond to HTML, JS and JSON requests:

```
def picture
  @picture = Picture.new params[:picture]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      format.html do
        logger.debug "In the HTML responder"
        redirect_to @picture
      end
      format.json { render json: @picture, status: :created, location: @picture }
      format.js { render :nothing => true }
    else
      # you get the idea
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to send a request to that controller with the `$.ajax` function (I can't use `:remote => true` in this specific situation - I'm trying to make ajax file upload work).

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("form#new_picture").attr("action"),
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
});
```

The problem is that my request is being treated as a HTML request for some reason. How do I tell rails that I want a JS response?

By the way, I'm using jquery_ujs in my project so I have access to the methods it provides if necessary. I'm not really good enough at JS to tweak that to do what I need here.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This solution didn't work for me (rails 3.1 + coffeescript). After searching quite a lot, I found the good way to do it and I wanted to share:

Just add ".js" to the end of the url. So simple...  ;-)

Comment: No better way to do that? Strange!

Comment: Dude, you are awesome :)

Comment: The issue with just adding .js to the URL, means that the request URL is not the same as the user's browser URL (because it has a .js at the end). This resulted in funny URLs being built via pagination from a page being returned via JS. Added `dataType: 'script'` as recommended by @shlensky seemed to work perfectly without changing the URL.

Answer (score 38):

Just add `dataType: 'script'`

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("form#new_picture").attr("action"),
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Comment: `dataType: 'script'` is for responding to `js` in Rails, `dataType: 'json'` is for responding to `json`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the 'accept' header before sending the ajax request so that Rails knows how to respond.

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("form#new_picture").attr("action"),
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, ' + settings.accepts.script);
  }
});
```

Comment: This was the accepted answer but I've changed it to @ndemoreau's answer since the '.js' concept became available.

Answer (score 6):

Add `dataType: 'script'` and in data of form add the parameter `format: 'js'` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/manager/consumers/url',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'script',
  data: {
  authenticity_token: '<%= form_authenticity_token %>',
  param_1: '1',
  param_2: '2',
  format: 'js'
  }
});
```

also add in the controller to not render layout:

```
  respond_to do |format|
      format.xls 
      format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
```

Answer (score 6):

Let me explain what is going on here.

I often get the Accept header and Content-type Header that a client sends to the server confused in HTTP. The Accept header is used to tell the server what content types (application/json, application/javascript, application/octet-stream, audio/mpeg, image/png, multipart/alternative, text/plain, text/html, text/csv, video/mpeg, etc) they'll accept. The server sends back a response, which includes the Content-Type header notifying the client of the actual Content Type of the content.

HTTP requests can also specify Content-Type, because in form data, there could be all types of data, and the Content-Type header can notify the server what the data actually is (e.g. multipart/form-data). The different media types like multipart/form-data are known as MIME.

Now jQuery.ajax() has another of parameters you can pass it related to this topic: accepts, contentType, dataType.

The contentType attribute is clear if you understand the Content-Type HTTP header. It tells the server what the data actually is. The default in jQuery is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases.

Remember that the Accept header tells the server what Content-Type it will accept. But when you read the jQuery documentation for dataType, it sounds quite similar: "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server." So what is the difference?

The accepts attribute allows you to change the Accept header in the request. But by changing the dataType it will change the Accept header too, so there is really no need to change the accept attribute; the dataType will change the Accept header. The benefit of dataType is ti allows you to pre-process the response before being available to the succes handler.

In effect, we need to tell Rails what we will accept as a response header, so we modify the dataType. In Rails the symbols :js and :json, for example, correspond to a HTTP Mime Type:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/javascript", :js, %w( application/javascript application/x-javascript )
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json, %w( text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

Thus, if we want to trigger the :js option in the respond_to block, then we need to specify the dataType in jQuery as script. And as one of the answers illustrates, you do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "users/populate_user,
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Now look how beautiful the Request Header looks:

[image]

Notice how specifying the dataType as script changed the Accept header to application/javascript. Also notice that the contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". Remember I said this is the default Content-Type jQuery will use if none is specified? Well another answer provided in this SO page specified this option as well:

```
  contentType: false
```

According to the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any
>   content type header.

One last point. In your Rails controller, you do not need to specify the :js flag if this controller action is only ever going to be responding to :js. You can simply omit the respond_to from the controller:

```
  def populate_user
    @user = User.from_names(params[:name][:value]).first
  end
```

And then add a users/populate_user.js.erb file. Also make sure your route is set up for a post request:

```
post 'users/populate_user', to: 'users#populate_user'
```

When copying and pasting answers from SO, it is also important to understand exactly what you are using in your project.

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether it is a xhr request and render the format you prefer. For Example;

```
if request.xhr?
  render :json => {
    :some_data => 'bla'
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Although possibly not directly answering the question, I came across this with a similar problem and others may find this helpful. Especially if you use haml.

After many attempts (including appending .js to the url) the only thing that worked for me was disabling the layout renderer when returning a script response.

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
```

My problem was that the AJAX response was a full html page generated by the rails layout template mechanism. This meant my javascript in my `thing.js.erb` wasn't executing. Disabling the layout meant only the javascript was returned (you can find the return in you browsers network tab of the developer pane) which allowed it to be executed.

I'm using haml as my default renderer and I believe that is why I required explicitly disabling the layout in js renders (I had assumed it would be automatic).

So if nothing else has worked and you use haml, try this.

Answer (score 1):

Set `contentType` as `"text/javascript"`

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("form#new_picture").attr("action"),
  type: "POST",
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: "text/javascript"
});
```