# jQuery bind ajax:success not working in rails 3 app for newly created (ajax) items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Edited this post because I found the problem is really in the inability of rails to bind to the ajax:success function.

***Using rails 3.2.3

Thanks for taking the time to read and try to help.

I am adding a simple fade out function on the ajax:success of an item being deleted, as follows:

```
$(document).ready( jQuery(function($) {
    $('.delete').bind('ajax:success', function() {
        $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
    });
}));
#For some reason had to pass the $ into the function to get it to work,
#not sure why this is necessary but doesn't work unless that is done.
```

After this, I wanted to create an object with unobtrusive jQuery when the user adds something, and have working delete buttons on those as well.  I made a create.js.erb file that is called after creating a new item - and the creation works fine, but the delete button cannot access the ajax:success event.

It does delete the data from the db when clicked, but the .fadeOut is never bound to it, so it doesn't disappear.  The create.js.erb is as follows:

```
#$("div").append(html) here, then call the function below to try and bind the ajax:success function
$('.delete').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
});
```

If I change this to bind to the click function, it works, but this doesn't account for a failed ajax call:

```
#$("div").append(html) here, then call the function below to try and bind the ajax:success function
    $('.delete').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
    });
```

So something must be up with binding to the ajax:success after the item is created.  You guys have any idea why this might be happening?  Do I need to do something special in rails to get the newly rendered item to recognize ajax events?  Any direction would be much appreciated!

P.S. The controller for the delete method is below in case anyone might be able to detect a problem there:

```
def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = @user.item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js { render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

Comment: Is this a Rails 3.0.x or 3.1/3.2 app?

Comment: Rails 3.2.3 is the version I'm using. It's very very possible I am just writing the code wrong but, because you asked which version of rails, I have to ask, do you know of a bug like this in earlier versions of rails or something like that?

Comment: Occasionally people will have jQuery and Prototype active on the same project. Happens more often with Rails 3.0.x. Now that I look at it again you may want to move the second bind (`bind_delete_animation`) into the `document.ready` rather than in a function called from the `document.ready`. I have never had success with the bind being outside the doc ready.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back and try to help.

I edited the stack overflow question a bit.  After playing around with it some more,  I found that the binding can work (if I bind to the 'click' event, for instance), the problem is it won't find to the ajax:success function.  I did move the bind directly into the document.ready just to see if it would change anything though, and am getting the same results.  Any idea why the ajax:success doesn't work for newly created items?

Comment: none of the suggestions on this question have worked for me

Answer (score 18):

The problem sounds like the bind is happening before the element is generated. Try this:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.delete', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, because my form handler method returned a plain string. Be sure to render something jQuery can process:

```
def handle_form
  ...
  render :json => {:what => 'ever'}
  # or
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: Same for me - I was rendering a plain string and it wouldn't work. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar things recently using Rails 3.2.3. I also use

```
$('#dialog-form').bind('ajax:success', function() {
})
```

and it works fine...

Comment: Actually I found out that as long as you render something in your controller, the ajax:success event will not work. Maybe Rails is trying to bind to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I have an updated answer for what works out to be the same issue.

As of version 1.9, jQuery will no longer consider an empty repsonse(render nothing: true) to be a success/done.  This means that in your controller you should return an empty JSON object instead.

`respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render: {}.to_json }
end`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get a parse error (or similar) by catching `ajax:completed`. Check the `status` argument there. In my case it was a `parseerror` due to a mimetype mismatch.

You can also set a breakpoint in `jquery_ujs.js`.

See also this question [jQuery ajax request not triggering JS response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919801/jquery-ajax-request-not-triggering-js-response-from-rails-controller)

Answer (score 0):

For me it's because we are using slim, and the templates are 'name.slim'. if we change them to 'name.slim.html', the ajax:success fires correctly.

The solution I am using is to add the format to the render declaration in the controller.

So we've got something like this:

```
render :new, layout: false, formats: [:html]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even it is an old question, none of the answers really helped me as I had a custom confirmation dialog and the ajax:success was triggering on totally different element.

In order to find which element is trigered by your ajax in such case, you can first use code:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', 'a', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
    // Check what is the value of $(this), and you will see what button has triggered the ajax success action, and you can start from there
});
```