# Rails 5 + Turbolinks + Jquery .ajax() actually showing .js.erb in view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I am upgrading an app from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.2.

In this app, there is a situation:

1. jQuery `$.ajax()` submits to requests#create with `type: 'POST', dataType: 'script'`.
2. The controller redirects to another action, maintaining `format: :js`.
3. The second action receives the call as JS and renders a `.js.erb` file.
4. In Rails 4, this `.js.erb` would run as it's supposed to.
5. In Rails 5, my webpage disappears and the `.js.erb` file is shown in the browser as-is.

My investigations ([example](https://m.patrikonrails.com/do-you-really-need-that-fancy-javascript-framework-e6f2531f8a38)) lead me to believe that this is due to Turbolinks, which likes to replace the page with whatever the response is from the server.

Update: removing turbolinks fixes the problem. I'd like to be able to fix it without disabling turbolinks.

How can I get the `.js.erb` to be run properly rather than simply rendered?

### Environment

ruby 2.6.3
rails 5.2.3
jquery-rails 4.3.3
turbolinks 5.2.0

### Code

There's lots of code overall. Here are the parts that seem to make the most sense to me: the AJAX call to the server and the server's response.

```
# jQuery:
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "script",
  url: "/requests?c=" + c_id,
  success: function(data){
    ...
  }
})

# second controller action
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

#### Related Questions

[Is it possible to disable Turbolinks for specific jQuery Ajax calls to prevent the page from refreshing and scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360956/is-it-possible-to-disable-turbolinks-for-specific-jquery-ajax-calls-to-prevent-t)

Comment: Did any answer from related question help you?

Comment: I tried many things but the only thing that's worked so far is removing Turbolinks entirely.